# Display Pivot Filter in a Cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

is there a way to display the filter setting of a pivot table in a cell above the table?

For example if I have a Row Value as a Date and apply a date filter between 22/6/2014 and 29/6/2014 I can't actually see the filter values unless I open up the filter dialog box again. It would be very useful if the value could be displayed somewhere for easy reference.

Can this be done?

Comment: just to point out I am using Excel 2007

Comment: I know, tell that to my conpany. Upgrade coming soon but needed a solution soon. :-(